# how to filter selected query with another condition in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, distinct-on

i have table as below

```
id  |  product_id  |  product_type_id |  closing_stock  |   created_dttm
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          2               1                  0               21-Nov-21
2          2               2                  9               21-Nov-21
3          2               3                  11              21-Nov-21
4          2               1                  7               20-Nov-21
```

i need to get last or recent records with  unique product_id, and product_type_id order by created_dttm desc.

so i have below query, but it is not fetching last or recent entered data due to closing_stock param > 0.

```sql
select distinct on(product_id, product_type_id) * 
from daily_stock
where product_id = 2 
and product_type_id in (1, 2, 3) 
and closing_stock > 0 
order by product_id, product_type_id , created_dttm desc
```

```
id  |  product_id  |  product_type_id |  closing_stock  |   created_dttm
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          2               2                  9               21-Nov-21
2          2               3                  11              21-Nov-21
3          2               1                  7               20-Nov-21
```

but i am expecting below results

```
id  |  product_id  |  product_type_id |  closing_stock  |   created_dttm
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2          2               2                  9               21-Nov-21
3          2               3                  11              21-Nov-21
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Why didn't you remov the condition `closing_stock > 0`?

Comment: i need the rows whose closing stock > 0, so i added that condition

Comment: But in your expected results the row with id=1 has closing_stock=0

Comment: yes i need latest records only  which has closing_stock > 0

Comment: Check what is written in your question under "but i am expecting below results". The 1st row with id=1 has closing_stock=0.

Comment: Thanks I corrected my expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause is applied before `DISTINCT ON`, filtering out all the rows with `closing_stock = 0`.
So, if any row with `closing_stock = 0` is the latest for a combination of `product_id` and `product_type_id` this combination will not be excluded from the results.

Remove the condition `closing_stock > 0` from your query and use it after you get the results:

```
select *
from (
  select distinct on(product_id, product_type_id) * 
  from daily_stock
  where product_id = 2 and product_type_id in (1, 2, 3)
  order by product_id, product_type_id, created_dttm desc
) t
where closing_stock > 0;
```

Or, with `row_number()` window function:

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by product_id, product_type_id order by created_dttm desc) rn
  from daily_stock
  where product_id = 2
) t
where rn = 1 and closing_stock > 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=24fc699cb56608835b5aaa0973cecd0f).

Comment: simple and straight forward solution..